# How can I find compatible dependency versions for my flutter project? (Firebase_auth, cloud_firestore, intl, flutter_dialogflow_v2)

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

So I have these dependencies which work fine together:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  
  #Firebase
  # cloud_firestore: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.4

  provider: ^4.3.2+1
  flutter_dialogflow_v2: ^0.3.2
  bubble: ^1.2.1
  intl: ^0.16.1

  material_design_icons_flutter: ^4.0.5955
  flutter_spinkit: "^4.1.2"
  auth_buttons: ^1.0.1+3
```

Now if I add cloud_firestore, no matter what version, I get this error:

> Because firebase_auth ^0.18.3+1 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^2.1.0 and firebase_auth >=0.18.0 <=0.18.3 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface >=2.0.0 <2.1.0, firebase_auth ^0.18.0 requires firebase_core_platform_interface >=2.0.0 <2.1.0 or ^2.1.0.
>
> And because cloud_firestore >=2.1.0 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^4.0.1, firebase_auth ^0.18.0 is incompatible with cloud_firestore >=2.1.0.

It seems that the firebase_core_platform_interface is the problem here because two dependencies depend on different versions.

Is there a way of checking the best version mix for this dependency setup?
I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set them all to `any`, then run `flutter pub get`.

Now you can look in the `pubspec.lock` file and see what versions you got and put them in `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, let me check this out...

Comment: No problem, have a nice day :)